Microsoft App Store is rejecting build with error code 1201
I am working on an UWP app. I am facing issue while making a release submission to Microsoft App store. App Store rejects the submission by mentioning error code 1201.
The same app is already in the store and previous versions were approved by store. Now suddenly form this version, store started rejecting it.
I am not getting any response from Microsoft Support team. I raised a ticket as well.
Certification Status:
This submission failed with error code(s) 1201,1201,1201,1201,1201,1201. More info about the error(s) can be found here. Once you make the required changes, Resubmit your product.
System Configuration:

App Architecture: x64
Kit Version: 10.0.22621.3233
OS Version: Microsoft Windows 11 Pro (10.0.22631.0)
OS Architecture: x64
Visual Studio: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) – Current Version 17.11.2

I am using following DLLs as well.
Bogus.dll, MimeKit.dll, BouncyCastle.Cryptography.dll, System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll,
System.Formats.Asn1.dll, System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.dll
App is always pass while using certification kit.

are you building th bundle for x64 or for ARM64?
Check your NuGet packages for updates and build again. Had some similar issues with ARM64 and got it working after dll update

@Mahobo I am building the bundle for x64 only.

According to similar issues, try to update NuGet and rebuild it.
